# Python does not find installed module

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, python-packaging

**EDIT:**
Thanks to  michcio1234, the problem is solved in the answer below.

**ORIGINAL QUESTION:**
I created a python package (called `precom`), installed via `pip install .` into a defined conda environment (also called `precom`) and tried to load the package.

When loading the installed package in `ipython`, it is not found.
However, when I do `conda list`, the package is listed (see output below).

This is really strange!

I googled, checked stack overflow, re-coded, re-installed but it never worked. Does anyone have an idea what I am missing?

```sh
(precom) C:\WINDOWS\system32>conda list
# packages in environment at C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\precom:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
ca-certificates           2019.5.15                     0
certifi                   2019.6.16                py37_0
git                       2.20.1               h6bb4b03_0
openssl                   1.1.1c               he774522_1
pip                       19.1.1                   py37_0
precom                    0.1                      pypi_0    pypi
python                    3.7.3                h8c8aaf0_1
setuptools                41.0.1                   py37_0
sqlite                    3.28.0               he774522_0
vc                        14.1                 h0510ff6_4
vs2015_runtime            14.15.26706          h3a45250_4
wheel                     0.33.4                   py37_0
wincertstore              0.2                      py37_0

(precom) C:\WINDOWS\system32>ipython
Python 3.6.5 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Mar 29 2018, 13:32:41) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 6.4.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

In [1]: import precom
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-e3942b1e7f0a> in <module>()
----> 1 import precom

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'precom'
```

Comment: Do you have a venv enabled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have `ipython` installed in your environment, so what you are running is not actually in your `precom` venv.

Try `pip install ipython` or `conda install ipython`, or just run `python` and then try to import your package.

Comment: OMG that's it. Unbelievable, I missed this. Thank you very much!